# unclosed html tag inside xslt

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt

I'd like to have unclosed html tag as a result of xslt. I'll add closing tag later in xslt. How can I achieve this? This one doesn't compile:

```
<xsl:when test="$href">
     <xsl:text><a href='{$href}'></xsl:text>
 </xsl:when>
```

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution on the net:

```
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<a href=']]></xsl:text>
                 <xsl:value-of select="href"/>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA['>]]></xsl:text>
```

Comment: please check my answer using disable-output-escaping should only be used as a last resort! and often used by people who misunderstand XSLT often leading to over-complicating otherwise simple solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of thing that you probably should want to avoid at all costs. I do not know your requirements but you perhaps want a link or a span tag based on something.

In these instances you can use something like this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="tag"/>
```

then 2 templates ie

```
<xsl:template match="tag">
    <span>hello king dave</span>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag[@href]">
    <a href="{@href}">link text....</a>    
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a definite answer without a better idea of the precise use case, but it's worth noting that you can use `match` *and* `name` on the same `<xsl:template>`.  For example, if you want to produce some particular output for all `<tag>` elements, but also wrap this output in an `<a>` tag in certain cases, then you could use an idiom like

```
<xsl:template match="tag[@href]">
  <a href="{@href}"><xsl:call-template name="tagbody" /></a>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag" name="tagbody">
  Tag content was "<xsl:value-of select="."/>"
</xsl:template>
```

The idea here is that `tag` elements with an `href` will match the first template, which does some additional processing before and after calling the general `tag` template.  Tags without an `href` will just hit the normal template without the wrapping logic.  I.e. for an input like

```
<root>
  <tag>foo</tag>
  <tag href="#">bar</tag>
</root>
```

you would get an output like

```
Tag content was "foo"
<a href="#">Tag content was "bar"</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before and was only able to solve it by copying the entire `<a href='{$href}'>...</a>` for each `when` branch.

Maybe you could try setting the `doctype` of your XSL to some loose XML standard, but afaik XSLT is pretty strict.

Edit: apparently you can set the doctype with a `<xsl:output>` tag.